# Android app Only For Phones

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

Is it possible to create Android app which can be downloaded from google play only by phone not tablet?

Comment: Android docs has info on this- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHandsetApps

Answer (score 19):

The answer for this always brings up the question of what you define as a "tablet". Do you include things like the Galaxy Note? It's still technically a phone but it's kind of on the borderline. My question would be what conditions make you want to restrict it? If you simply want to require that it be able to make calls, you can add a feature tag to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/>
```

Which will require the device to have the dialer and a data network (which should exclude a large majority of tablet devices).

Comment: This is much more appropriate that any other screen density fixes, provided the application uses phone calls or sms functionality.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify which devices should see your app on Google Play in your AndroidManifest :

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize=["small" | "normal" | "large"] />
</compatible-screens>
```

By removing xlarge, you remove all the 10" Tablet.

For info :

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

More infos on Android developer site : 
 - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html
 - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

Comment: Galaxy S3 is large. It's 1280 x 720px but xhdpi. don't forget screenSize is in dp not px.

Answer (score 2):

use compatible-screens on your manifest

More here : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html