# app only for phones not tablets

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, google-play

I am trying to build an android app which can be downloaded only by phone not tablet.I have put this into the manifest:

```
<supports-screens
        android:resizeable="false"
        android:anyDensity="false"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="false" />
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
```

**Question**:

1.When I am running my app in the tablet emulator,it is not giving any error. What am I doing wrong ? Does it only work when I submit it on playstore? If that's so then how can I test my app before making it live ?

2.As I have written here `android:screenDensity="xhdpi"`,how to support `xxhdpi`? As an example nexus5 is `xxhdpi`.

**Note :**

By tablet I mean that the resolution isn't higher than *1440x2560* and the screen size 
isn't more than *6 inch* and offcourse it doesn't support calling facility.

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319476/android-app-only-for-phones) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230554/how-to-restrict-app-to-android-phones-only) but with no luck.

Comment: yes, those restrictions are only for google play.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you want.
There exists an overlapping between tablets & phones screen density.
Some tablets are of screen density as phone and vice versa.
What you can do is after using some restriction from manifest remove unwanted devices from playstore.